# GAE returns Nonetype when entity clearly exists in datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

When the user creates a new event, they input "event_name" and "event_time" and select the location from a dropdown list. I then retrieve the latitude and longitude of the event from the PlaceModel instance that matches the location.

The problem is, localhost returns Nonetype when the PlaceModel instance I'm looking for exists.

My models:

```
class PlaceModel(db.Model):
    place_name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    place_lat = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    place_long = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    def render(self):
        return render_str("placemodel.html", p = self)

class EventModel(db.Model):
    event_place = db.ReferenceProperty(PlaceModel)

    event_name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    event_time = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    def render(self):
        return render_str("eventmodel.html", e = self)
```

The html:

```
<select name = "place_name">
{% for place in allplaces %}
    <option name = "place_name" value = {{place_name}}> {{place.place_name}}</option>
{%endfor%}
</select>
```

The python:

```
class NewEvent(Handler):
   def get(self):
        if self.user:
            allplaces = PlaceModel.all()
            self.render("newevent.html", allplaces = allplaces)
        else:
            self.redirect("/signup")

   def post(self):
        event_name = self.request.get("event_name")
        event_time = self.request.get("event_time")
        place_name = self.request.get_all("place_name")

        if event_name and event_time and place_name:
            place_lat = PlaceModel.gql("where place_name = :place_name", place_name = place_name).get().place_lat
            place_long = PlaceModel.gql("where place_name = :place_name", place_name = place_name).get().place_long

            event_place = PlaceModel(parent = place_key(), 
                            place_name = place_name, place_lat = place_lat, place_long = place_long)

            event = EventModel(parent = event_key(),
                    event_name = event_name, event_time = event_time, 
                    event_place = event_place)

            event.put()
            stat = "your event has been recorded"
            self.render('newevent.html', stat = stat)
        else:
            allplaces = PlaceModel.all()

            error = "fill in all the boxes"
            self.render("newevent.html", error = error, allplaces = allplaces,
                        event_name = event_name, event_time = event_time)
```

What's wrong?? Why is gql returning nonetype?

Edit:
The (latter part of) the error log:

```
File "/Users/yingjiefu/Documents/munchkin/munchkin.py", line 195, in post
    place_lat = PlaceModel.gql("where place_name = :place_name", place_name = place_name).get().place_lat
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'place_lat'
```

EDIT: It works now!

the python:

```
class NewEvent(Handler):
   def get(self):
        if self.user:
            allplaces = PlaceModel.all()
            self.render("newevent.html", allplaces = allplaces)
        else:
            self.redirect("/signup")

   def post(self):
        event_name = self.request.get("event_name")
        event_time = self.request.get("event_time")
        place_name = self.request.get("place_name")

        if event_name and event_time and place_name:
            place = PlaceModel.all().filter("place_name", place_name).get()
            place_lat = place.place_lat
            place_long = place.place_long


            event = EventModel(parent = event_key(),
                    event_name = event_name, event_time = event_time, 
                    event_place = place)

            event.put()
            stat = "your event has been recorded"
            allplaces = PlaceModel.all()
            self.render('newevent.html', stat = stat, allplaces = allplaces)
        else:
            allplaces = PlaceModel.all()

            error = "fill in all the boxes"
            self.render("newevent.html", error = error, allplaces = allplaces,
                        event_name = event_name, event_time = event_time)
```

the html:

```
<select name = "place_name" >
{% for place in allplaces %}
    <option value = "{{ place.place_name }}">{{ place.place_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: what is the exact full text of the error?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with this code.

I expect that the main one is in how you define the values in the option. Not only do you fail to wrap it in quotes, but you actually use a non-existent variable: `place_name`. It should look like this:

```
<option name="place_name" value="{{place_name}}">{{place.place_name}}</option>
```

Secondly, you use `get_all()` when extracting the `place_name` value from the request. As I understand it, that returns a **list**, so you would have multiple values in the placeholder in the GQL. You should use `get()` as you do for the other variables.

Thirdly, not related to your question, but why are you doing the exact same query twice? That costs you twice as much, for no reason. Get it once and store it in a variable:

```
place = PlaceModel.gql("where place_name = :place_name", place_name=place_name).get()
place_lat = place.place_lat
place_long = place.place_long
```

(I won't even ask why you want to use GQL instead of the normal Query syntax, which would be much shorter: `PlaceModel.all().filter('place_name', place_name)` - you do realize that they both get translated into the same RPC calls, and GQL isn't in any way more "native" than the model version?)

Comment: I switched to gql after trying the normal query syntax because I got an error saying you can't filter lists. I changed the the get_all() to get(), but now it's not getting any value for "place_name" and I get the error page re-render. (I added the quote wrap too)

Comment: Also, how is place_name non-existent? It's a required property for PlaceModel and I retrieve the value for it from the dropdown list